# Determine internet IP address in shell?

Tags: linux, macos, shell

I'm trying to save my internet IP address to a variable in the shell.

I tried

```
ip=`host 'localhost' | awk '{print $4}'`
```

But that returns

```
127.0.0.1
```

How to save internet IP address to a variable in the shell?

Comment: What IP? Your WAN (external) IP?

Comment: My ip for my local internet, not 77.somethingother

Comment: But 192.somethingelse

Comment: Only local wifi

Comment: Try `ifconfig | grep inet | cut -d ' ' -f 2 | cut -d ':' -f 2`.

Comment: Also see [How can I get my external IP address in a shell script?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/22615/56041) on [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) and [Command for determining my public IP?](https://askubuntu.com/q/95910) on Ubuntu Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get IP addresses of all you local interfaces, try using `ifconfig`, for example like this:

```
$ ifconfig | awk '/inet / { print $2 }'
127.0.0.1
10.8.0.34
192.168.1.2
```

Here you can see I have 3 addresses (the loopback adapter, ethernet and wifi). If you know your local network address has `192.*` form, you can get only that one with:

```
$ ifconfig | awk '/inet *192/ { print $2 }'
192.168.1.2
```

And to store it into a variable:

```
ip=$(ifconfig | awk '/inet *192/ { print $2 }')
```

Or, to store all addresses in a `bash` array:

```
$ ips=($(ifconfig | awk '/inet / { print $2 }'))
$ printf "ip: %s\n" "${ips[@]}"
ip: 127.0.0.1
ip: 10.8.0.34
ip: 192.168.1.2
```

To get IPv6 addresses, look for `inet6` instead of `inet`.